# regex extraction 2 groups resulting only in one match

Tags: python, regex

New to regex.
Consider you have the following text structure:
`"hello_1:45||hello_2:67||bye_1:45||bye_5:89||.....|| bye_last:100"` and so on
I want to build a dictionary out of it taking the string value as a key, and the decimal number as the dict value.
I was trying to check my concept using [this nice tool](https://regex101.com/)
I wrote my regex expression:

```
(\w+):(\d+)
```

And got only one match ->the first in the string : hello_1:45
I tried also something like:
`.*(\w+):(\d+).*`
But also not good, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `g` (global) modifier to get all the matches and not stop to the first one. In python you can use the `re.findall` function to get all the matches. Check the example [here](https://regex101.com/r/vT6vK5/1).

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this only through split function.

```
s = "hello_1:45||hello_2:67||bye_1:45||bye_5:89"
print {i.split(':')[0]:i.split(':')[1] for i in s.split('||')}
```

Try this if you want to convert the value part as int.

```
print {i.split(':')[0]:int(i.split(':')[1]) for i in s.split('||')}
```

or

```
print {i.split(':')[0]:float(i.split(':')[1]) for i in s.split('||')}
```